# a person who calls out for eliciting ideas from others and does what he wants

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

What expression would you use for a impressionable person (a decision maker like a boss or potential customer) who comes to your facility (office, shop, garage, showroom) makes you do all the leg work for an critical suggestion/advice, promises you of a deal and then just for a sake of second opinion goes with his chosen/favorite dealer having contradicting advice and placidly comes informing you of superseding deal blissfully oblivious of his misconduct.

Comment: Benign time waster?

Comment: Does "two-timer" fit the bill

Comment: Could you re-phrase that at least two different ways, please? What you actually posted was either pointless or obvious; perhaps even both…

Comment: Also, are you looking for something you can call them to their face or behind their back?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the person is "unreceptive", to the ideas or suggestions of others.

> unreceptive
>  adj
>   1. not tending to receive new ideas or suggestions favourably
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unreceptive)

Or, considering they originally sought ideas but rejected them anyway, I'd say they're "dismissive", of other suggestions.

> dismissive
>  adjective
>       Feeling or showing that something is unworthy of consideration.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dismissive)